# Android, Start App on Launch of Emulator

Tags: java, android

I want to do some testing on the Android emulator to run an app of mine automatically and pass it a parameter how can I do this?

For now lets assume, I have an app that opens a URL (parameter) in a browser. How can I get my emulator to do this upon launch of app?

This is for testing and this app will not be give to other to be used.

Thanks all

Comment: You could write an app that does this, run the app in eclipse and it will start an emulator, install the app. Do this every time you start the emulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to add the "boot completed" permission, then add an intent for the broadcast and make a broadcastreceiver:

--in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

--and also in the manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".receiver.BootReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

--then make a receiver:

```
public class MyBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       //use an intent to stat your activity here!   
    }
}
```